Why does `os.execl` interfere with `stdin` on Windows?
My minimal example is null.py:
import os, sys
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable)

I would have thought that python null.py would be pretty much the same as running python, which is the case on Ubuntu 22.04. However, on Windows 11, it seems to mess up stdin dramatically; for example, if I press a key, it may or may not appear on the screen, and pressing Enter mostly does nothing. This does not happen if I replace os.execl(...) with os.system(sys.executable). Is there a better way to exec under Windows?

I flagged this as a dupe of os.exec on Windows, but I'm not really sure tbh.

Well, at least the answer is evident from that link. There is no way to replace a process in Windows. There is no reason to try to get exec to work. Just do something like def execl(*args): subprocess.call([a for a in args]) on Windows.
